# How to name a selector which may generate an error?

Tags: objective-c

I am having trouble with naming my selector, which accepts a single parameter: a pointer to a pointer to an NSError instance. What is the best practice of doing that?

Right now I have something like:

```
- (void)loadContentIfNeededAndGenerateError:(NSError **)error;
```

But it doesn't look like a good way to name a selector.

Comment: So long as the name is properly descriptive then it is a good name

Comment: I would call it `loadContentIfNeeded:`.

Comment: Alas, not every scenario names well, given the Objective-C "standard".  (I would perhaps say "WithError" or "ReportingError".)  (Or at least spell "Generate" correctly.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple use the naming convention `WithError:`, so I guess:

```
- (BOOL)loadContentIfNeededWithError:(NSError **)error;
```

Note: Return `BOOL` and don't rely on the non-`nil` state of `error` in order to detect the error.

In other words:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![self loadContentIfNeededWithError:&error]) {
    // React to error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just:

```
- (BOOL)loadContentIfNeeded:(NSError **)error;
```

I take my precedent from NSManagedObjectContext's:

```
- (BOOL)save:(NSError **)error;
```